# Put labels sloped along axes in ListPlot3D

Tags: graphics3d, plotting, labeling, alignment

The three text labels in the following figure are all in horizontal direction.

> How to put the labels sloped along each axis to which it is attached?

**My Code**

```
data = Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 0, Pi, Pi/5}, {j, 0, Pi, Pi/5}];    
testGraph = 
 ListPlot3D[data, Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
  ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors", 
  AxesLabel -> {"Number of Processes", "Number of Operations", 
    "Time (ms)"},
  ImageSize -> 350]
```

**My Figure**

[image: listplot3d-label-test]

**Desired Effect**

I want the labels to be sloped along axes, just like in the following figure (made by Python; Please ignore other elements but the labels).

[image: labels]

---

**Note:** The answer given below by @eldo uses hard-coded angles. Do you have better solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
testGraph =
 ListPlot3D[data,
  Mesh -> None,
  InterpolationOrder -> 3,
  ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors",
  AxesLabel -> 
   {Rotate["Number of Processes", - 20 Degree], 
    Rotate["Number of Operations", 60 Degree], 
    Rotate["Time (ms)", 95 Degree]},
  ImageSize -> 450]
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that the angles are hard-coded such that I have to tune them every time I rotate the figure. Anyway, this approach works. Thanks. (I will leave the post "open" for a while before accepting your answer to see whether there are better solutions).

Comment: Yes, they are. Theoretically it should be possible to build a lookup-table to get the "slopes" (degrees) from the most common `ViewPoint`-settings. But I doubt that anybody here would like to do this.